# Finding keywords in SQL script

Tags: t-sql, ssms

I have a list of 50 columns in a database that are likely to change or be removed within the next few months. I have a task to identify any SQL scripts that reference these tables. Up until now, I have been doing this by eye however, I have come across some huge scripts that will take forever to use this method. I'm also getting a little sick and tired of doing it :)

I would like to be able to search through a script with the 50 table.column names and if there is a hit, I can do further, manual investigation.

Can anyone recommend a product? Freeware would be best as I don't really want to use my own money to pay for the solution.

Comment: By scripts do you mean actual SQL files? Or procedures/views/functions etc?

Comment: I mean just searching through SQL code that is open in SSMS

Comment: Isn't this a bit the same as your other question (http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/121346/need-to-get-identify-all-tables-and-columns-in-a-sql-query)?

Comment: Hi Marco, I think the question is different but it is to achieve the same result. Instead of outputting all tables and columns I was hoping to just search for all of them in one go.

Comment: Some sample data and desired output would be good.

Answer (score 0):

ApexSQL Search - http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_search.aspx

free tools, search database object (for this tasks) - search code for columns name